# Can I use a for loop iterator in the parameter of an arrow function to be passed into the loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, arrow-functions

I am programming a physics simulation, and the current version is on my website. I don't know if I can post the link, so I won't. The program is a multi-link inverted pendulum, and I am trying to write functions for running the physics. To do this, I have to set a lot of arrays for the different values of each inverted pendulum, such as an array for all of the moment-of-intertias, the masses, the thetas, and more. This is how I am doing it right now:

```
    function fillArray(begin, end, alg) {
        let arr = [];

        for (let i = begin; i < end; i++) {
            arr[i] = alg();
        }
        return arr;
    }

    let Ls = fillArray(0, numPoles, () => 2 * this.ls[i]);
```

When I output the Ls array, it says that every element within is Nan (not a number). What am I doing wrong? How can I make this work?

Comment: Can you expand on why sparse arrays are a bad idea? Also I understand that the i is outside, but how do I get the same functionality inside?

Comment: Where is `ls` (starting with a lowercase 'l', not `Ls`) defined?

Comment: what is `ls` and where is `i` declared for this scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the `alg()` function is passed outside the loop where contains a variable `i`. 
   `this.ls[i]` is `undefined` where `i` is `undefined` 
   so `2 * undefined` return `NaN`
2. `this.ls` is not in the function scope so the arrow function should use global ls or you have to pass it into the function.
3. Try the following code

```js
function fillArray(begin, end, alg) {
 let arr = [];
 for (let i = begin; i < end; i++) {
  arr[i] = alg(i);
 }
 return arr;
}
let ls = [1,3,11,22];
let numPoles = 3;
let Ls = fillArray(0, numPoles, (i) => 2 * ls[i]);
console.log(Ls);
```

Comment: YES. This is amazing, thank you. I got back on to work on it today, and I found out the issue was exactly what you thought. I used k, and I came up with it on my own, but we need more people like you! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be a lot easier to use `Array.from` inline, rather than calling another standalone function:

```js
const obj = {
  ls: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  makeLs: function() {
    const numPoles = 5;
    const Ls = Array.from({ length: numPoles }, (_, i) => 2 * this.ls[i]);
    console.log(Ls);
  },
};

obj.makeLs();
```

Closer to your original code, you could modify it by having `alg` accept a parameter, as `i`:

```js
const obj = {
  ls: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  makeLs: function() {
    function fillArray(begin, end, alg) {
      let arr = [];
      for (let i = begin; i < end; i++) {
        arr[i] = alg(i);
      }
      return arr;
    }
    const numPoles = 5;
    let Ls = fillArray(0, numPoles, (i) => 2 * this.ls[i]);
    console.log(Ls);
  },
};

obj.makeLs();
```